# How to create a leaderboard using firebase

Tags: android, firebase

To set up a "leaderboard" in my android app, I started learning firebase recently. What I want to do is get the user datas from the database, rearrange them according to their scores, and generate the leaderboard that is stored on firebase. Every time when there is new user data input, the new leaderboard will be generated automatically. But I cannot find how to do it, and in the tutorials I can only see how to "write&read".  Can someone give me a hint? Thank you so much.

Comment: You question is not clear,Please elaborate what you really want to do..

Comment: Done. Hope it is now clear enough.

Comment: This is a very open-ended question and not very well suited for Stack Overflow. After going over the Firebase documentation, consider taking any questions like this to the firebase-talk forum to generate a discussion. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood from your question is that you wanna make an app that will display the user rank in the app.

To achieve leaderboard code you can arrange data in `leaderboard` key.
Where each user registered will be created with `user_id` obtained as a key and within the `user_id` key store the user info like `name, rank, level,etc`
For leaderboard you can order the according to rank.

For Example

```
{
  "leaderboard":{
    "xyz":{
      "name":"xyz1323",
      "rank":234,
      "email_id":"xyz@gmail.com"
    },
    "pqr":{
         "name":"pqr1323",
      "rank":1,
      "email_id":"pqr@gmail.com"
    },
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

where xyz and pqr are the user_id which are obtained when user is signed in or created.
You will need to handle condition that while signing in user new user not to be created if already exist, it can be done with `datasnapshot.exist()`

Thanks